# Azure functions get service bus brokeredMessage with nodejs

Tags: node.js, azureservicebus, azure-functions

Is there a way to retrieve the service bus brokered message from a javascript azure function.
At this time there's only a context that containing an invocationId, but not all properties like brokeredProperties or customPropeties.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is no way to do this from node functions. You'd have to use C# and specify a `BrokeredMessage` as your parameter type, in which case you'd be given the entire message to handle yourself.

There is an issue filed to expose more details for Service Bus (and Event Hub) triggers: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1004. I've added a link to this question so we can make sure we've taken your scenario into account when we address it.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, all of the Service Bus custom properties are available in `context.bindingData.properties` object.

In my case:

```
properties: 
{ 
    type: 'sometype',   // <- this is the property I have set manually in IoT Device-to-Cloud message
    'iothub-connection-device-id': 'mydeviceid',
    'iothub-connection-auth-method': '{"scope":"somescope","type":"sometype","issuer":"external","acceptingIpFilterRule":null}',
    'iothub-connection-auth-generation-id': 'someid' // <- These are added by IoT Hub
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to set service bus properties as part of the output binding?

Comment: indeed, but this is for in binding, but for out binding seems no way to do it.